# Emoji icon appear as white color in the tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, emoji

Emoji icon appear as white color in the tableView. This happens when scrolling through the tableview (probably because of `dequeueReusableCell`).
I get the list from my phone contacts, when name contains emoji.

[image: Emoji icon as white circle]